# Errors with importing 'set_random_seed' from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     34 from keras.utils.np_utils import normalize
     35 from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
---> 36 from keras.utils.tf_utils import set_random_seed
     37 from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
     38 from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

ImportError: cannot import name 'set_random_seed' from 'keras.utils.tf_utils' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/tf_utils.py)
```

As shown above, I'm facing problem with importing 'set_random_seed' from keras
Though I see that in the latest TensorFlow version (2.7.0)

set_random_seed(...): Sets all random seeds for the program (Python, NumPy, and TensorFlow).

Environment:

Packages: TensorFlow 2.7, Keras 2.7,

Comment: since u are using TF2.7, use tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed)